# SparkSql query to get just previous and next row from cassandra for a defined value

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

We have to write a SparkSQL query to get just previous and just next row of a specific value.
Let's say, our table structure in Cassandra is like below

```
id, timestamp
1, 100
2,200
3,300
4,400
```

Now I have to write a Spark Query to get only two rows, and out of these two rows, first row's value should be less than 300 which is (2,200) and second row's value should be greater than 300 which is (4,400). And I do not want to perform order by operation because of high data volume. In case of high data volume, order by the operation will be slow.
We can understand the requirement like this, suppose I want two get just previous and just next row from a table whose timestamp value is : -
For the first row: should be less than 300 so expected row is (2, 200)
For the second row: should be greater than 300 so expected row is (4, 400)
And the output should be like below

```
2,200
4,400
```

But this should be performed without order by operation.

Comment: What does "previous" and "next" mean? Is it based on the order on `id` or order on `timestamp`? Or is it based on the current order of records in the DF (which could be unpredictable)?

Comment: Rows are in ascending  order by timestamp field.

Comment: And I want to get : 
1, one row for which timestamp value is less than 300 so In output result it should return (2, 200)
2. and another one row for which timestamp value is greater than 300, so in output it should return (4, 400)
And this should be done without order by operation. Because data size in cassandra table is too large. SO we can not perform order by operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the RDD API, making an index column that is shifted up or down to simulate a sliding operation:

```
#Obtain an index for each element
df_id = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()\
         .map(lambda row: Row(id=row[0].id, timestamp=row[0].timestamp, idx=row[1]))\
         .toDF()
previousDF = df_id.rdd\
          .map(lambda row: Row(previous_id=row.id, previous_timestamp=row.timestamp, idx=row.idx+1))\
          .toDF()
nextDF = df_id.rdd\
          .map(lambda row: Row(next_id=row.id, next_timestamp=row.timestamp, idx=row.idx-1))\
          .toDF()
```

Now perform a join on the `idx` column to join the original DF with other the others:

```
df_id.join(previousDF, on='idx')\
     .join(nextDF, on='idx')\
     .show()
```

The result looks like:

```
+---+---+---------+-----------+------------------+-------+--------------+
|idx| id|timestamp|previous_id|previous_timestamp|next_id|next_timestamp|
+---+---+---------+-----------+------------------+-------+--------------+
|  1|  2|      200|          1|               100|      3|           300|
|  2|  3|      300|          2|               200|      4|           400|
+---+---+---------+-----------+------------------+-------+--------------+
```

The inner join on all these DFs results in some missing entries on the "previous" and "next" sides. But you could perform one-by-one joins if interested in looking at either just the previous or the next records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...But will it be good for large data in Cassandra table? 

Because in our case we will get let's say 1 lac rows from kafka then we have to do the same operation(getting previous and next row from Cassandra for each incoming row from kafka)

Comment: @RajendraJangir If this is being done at such a fine level, then why do you do it in spark to begin with? It could be much more easily done with a normal Java/Scala/etc program that fetches records as needed... Right? Also, the data being sourced from Kafka, wouldn't you be able to use spark streaming and use its built-in sliding window functionality?

Comment: Yes, You were right.
Thank you very much for all your valuable answers and suggestions.